# Server Sent Events (SSE) works on Ubuntu 14.04, but not Windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, server-sent-events

In my application I'm using SSE to send status notifications to update the page information. The events get through reliably on browsers with Ubuntu 14.04, so I know they work in some circumstances. However, the exact same browser does not receive the same event on Windows 10.

The browsers I attempted are Chrome - 55.0.2883.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 50.1.0. The results are the same in both: Windows gets no events, Ubuntu gets all of them. I would like some ideas for what to look into to fix this problem.

Issues I think it is not:

- hardware, since I have both operating systems on the same device
- SSE client limit
- Windows Firewall,  I disabled all profiles (Domain Profile, Private Profile, Public Profile).

Comment: Had some discussion with some colleagues and the issue may have something to do with the underlying HTTP library for the operating systems. This would explain the difference between Windows (https only) and Linux (http and https).

Comment: Re: Both OS on the same device. Is one be hosted in the other? And is the website you are testing on a remote server? 
For troubleshooting, I'd suggest to look at the debug console, the network tab in particular, and see if that gives any clues. E.g. do you see the connection being made? Does it immediately fail, or is the connection being held open but no data is arriving?

Comment: The website is hosted on a separate device on the local network. The issue I am having is with the operating system that the client is using. Something I noticed is that on creation of the EventSource object when the client has the correct authentication, it doesn't receive any events. However, when the client is not authenticated, the events are able to get through and tells the client that the session for SSE was closed.

Comment: After looking into it more, it looks like something is going on with input/output buffers. The events are getting sent, but it's not getting all the way to my javascript code.

On Windows 10, using HTTP, without proper authentication, the EventSource object is created, then the "open" event comes through, then session is destroyed an the server.

On Windows 10, using HTTP, WITH proper authentication, the EventSource object is created, nothing comes through. But when I log out and the session is destroyed on the server, THEN the "open" event comes through.

Comment: My question about which OS is hosting the other was because the hosted OS has another layer to go through, and sockets might not be held open. Or it might be doing some "intelligent" caching. Or it might affect CORS behaviour. (If it is simply a dual boot system, then of course this is not applicable.)

Comment: Yes, the client device that I was using is dual-booting; I am not using any virtualization.

Comment: This was my question before. [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769730/server-sent-events-read-json-and-update-clients). Then I fixed it my self.  Now... I'm having the above issue on Windows 7 / Windows 10 with WAMP or XAMPP. I have developed an SSE in my Macbook Pro with MAMPP. Works fine, No issues I found. Then I deployed to client Server. Windows 10 with WAMP. In Localhost also SSE not working. Then installed XAMPP. But still the same. Again I did the same setup in Windows 7 with WAMP and XAMPP. Not working. What can be the problem?